# Why does this wildcard search string return 'pattern match not valid'?

Tags: replace, ms-word, find, wildcard

In Word's Find and replace dialogue, with Wildcards turned on, the below works

```
^013[1]. (*)^013(*)^013[2]. (*)^013(*)^013[3]. (*)^013(*)^013[4]. (*)^013(*)^013[5]. (*)^013
```

The below does not work.

```
^013[1]. (*)^013(*)^013[2]. (*)^013(*)^013[3]. (*)^013(*)^013[4]. (*)^013(*)^013[5]. (*)^013(*)^013
```

It returns the message below

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The only difference is ***(*)^013*** on the end of the second search string. Unless I'm missing it, number 5 is the same as all the other parts of the find string, but Word returns an error.

Doing this hurt my eyes and brain so it's possible I made a typo, but don't see anything like that. What is going wrong?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey5aW.png

Comment: I can confirm the error. But if you e.g. remove the first part and search for `^013(*)^013[2]. (*)^013(*)^013[3]. (*)^013(*)^013[4]. (*)^013(*)^013[5]. (*)^013(*)^013` it works. So it is not the last `^013` but propably some other limits like e.g. max number of placeholders etc.

Comment: If you remove the first `(*)` and search for `^13[1]. ^13(*)^13[2]. (*)^13(*)^13[3]. (*)^13(*)^13[4]. (*)^13(*)^13[5]. (*)^13(*)^13` it works. So it is not the last `^013` but more likely the number of `(*)` that crashes. `(*)(*)(*)(*)(*)(*)(*)(*)(*)(*)` = 10 times `(*) throws the same error wherèas 9 times `(*)` are ok.

Comment: Thanks, I wondered if it was some kind of character limit but I couldn't figure out what. Why don't you make it an answer and become the first person on the internet to document this fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the first `(*)` and search for #`^13[1]. ^13(*)^13[2]. (*)^13(*)^13[3]. (*)^13(*)^13[4]. (*)^13(*)^13[5]. (*)^13(*)^13` it works.

So it is not the last ^013 but more likely the number of (*) that crashes.

`(*)(*)(*)(*)(*)(*)(*)(*)(*)(*)` = 10 times `(*)` throws the same error whereas 9 times `(*)` are ok.